# Unable to locate package libtecla1-dev

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, raspberry-pi4

I am using Ubuntu mate in raspberry pi 4, I wanted to install bladeRF driver , on the process of installing dependencies ,I am unable to install libtecla1-dev package, although I have installed libtecla1 and libtecla-dev. Please help me to get a solution for installing the package, or is the libtecla1-dev is obsoleted already?